# bootstrap 3 dialog shown not event not firing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I used the below syntax

```js
$('#modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(event){
    alert('some');
});
```

but don't know what is the reason it just don't work..

I use the opposite code like

```js
$('#modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(event){
    alert('some');
});
```

I work just fine..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Refer to this [pull request](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/4b1a6e11326fee97a5ebc194be040086f40f97fb) (looks like it is a bug)

Change this line in `bootstrap.js` on line 907 from:

```js
that.$element.find('.modal-dialog') // wait for modal to slide in
```

To:

```js
that.$element // wait for modal to slide in
```

Comment: I don't have modal.js

Comment: Search for it in your `bootstrap.js` file then. It's on line 907

Comment: It doesn't look like they merged the [pull request](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/4b1a6e11326fee97a5ebc194be040086f40f97fb) (404) or officially fixed the bug yet. Regardless, thanks for the workaround!

Comment: I assume this is because you're supposed to have a `.modal-dialog` inside the `.modal` in Bootstrap 3. I modified my modal structure and styling and had to override this as well.